# CodeIgniter 3 - Estrutura de subdiretórios - Rotas

Tags: php, codeigniter, rotas, codeigniter-3

Criei um projeto no CI e estou passando pelo seguinte problema:
Dividi meus controllers em duas pastas:

```
application/controllers/painel/
```

e

```
application/controllers/site/
```

Sendo que no subdiretório painel tem o controller Home e no site também.

Eu queria definir o controler home do subdiretório site como controller default. Tentei fazer isso nas rotas, colocando:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'site/home'
```

e também

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'site/index/home'
```

mas não deu certo, alguém pode me ajudar???

Comment: Se minha resposta resolveu, aceite a resposta por favor. Se você achou a solução sozinho, também pode postar sua resposta para ajudar outras pessoas. Ou ainda pode pedir mais esclarecimentos sobre minha resposta nos comentários da resposta.

Comment: Essas rotas já estão configuradas dessa forma. Mas o que eu queria mesmo era definir o home do diretório site como controller default. Usar as rotas dessa forma não definem o controller default.

Answer (score 3):

No arquivo `application/config/routes.php`precisa adicionar uma rota para cada `home`. Ficaria assim:

```
$route['painel'] = "painel/home";
$route['site'] = "site/home";
```